# How do I use WHERE and AND for 2 fields?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I've encountered an error when using - which I presume is the problem, mysql_fetch_assoc.

```
<?php
$buildingNames = $_POST['buildingName'];
$roomId = $_POST['roomId'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
                      FROM forestcourt 
                     WHERE buildingName=$buildingNames AND 
                           id=$roomId");

$id2 = 'id';
$buildingName = 'buildingName';
$subBuildings = 'subBuildings';
$imagePath = 'imagePath';
$description = 'description';

$rows2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo 'Name: ' . $rows2[$buildingName] . '<br/>' . 'Room Number: ' . $rows2[$id2]
     . '<br/>' . 'Sub Buildings: ' . $rows2[$subBuildings] . '<br/>'
     . 'Description: ' . $rows2[$description] . '<br/>' . 'Location: ' 
     . '<img src="../' . $rows2[$imagePath] . '"/>' . '<br/><br/>';
?>
```

The code above is what I'm using to get form data from a page before this one;

```
    <Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="result.php">

       Building Name: <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" Name ="buildingName">
       Room Number: <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" Name ="roomId">
       <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit" VALUE = "Go">

    </FORM>
```

What the site is meant to do is use the $_POST from the form and send it over to the results.php page using the FORM ACTION attribute.

However, when it's run it comes up with an error saying;

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
>   result resource in
>   /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage23/ed/ge/_g/xxx.co.uk/public_html/testing/result.php
>   on line 52

line 52 is;

```
$rows2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

which refers to;

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                      FROM forestcourt 
                     WHERE buildingName=$buildingNames AND 
                           id=$roomId");
```

So I presume that something is wrong with my SELECT statement?

I'm pretty new to SQL so I can't see anything wrong with it.

The database is connected and does get results from tables.
the name of the fields are also correct.

If anyone could point anything out or help that would be great.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @Prix - It seems that you *over-edited* here. The first line is cryptic.

Comment: @PM77-1 use utf-8 on your browser. I see no issues here I haven't changed anything but spaces and newlines and the title.

Comment: have you tried to echo `$buildingNames`and `$roomId` before the query ? and see if there is values ?

Comment: Thanks for the editing Prix.

Comment: @nickb i've not looked into securing my code for SQL injections but it is something that I will be looking into before I do sign off the final version of it.

echo_me i'll give that a try now and see what happens.

Comment: @EHU-Lewis you should look into it now since you are using mysql_* library **which is a deprecated library and will most likely be removed on further versions**, so you can kill 2 rabbits with a single stone, protect against SQL injections and migrate to PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements.

Comment: @echo_Me i've done the echo and it shows up the 2 values entered so I know that the values are being passed between the 2 pages.

Comment: @EHU-Lewis try my answer bellow.

Comment: @echo_Me thanks for that. It works perfectly now. I'm going to look into that SQL injection prevention and PDO / MySQLi now. Hopefully it won't be too hard to transfer everything over!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes around `WHERE buildingName='$buildingNames' AND id='$roomId'`

Also to avoid SQL injections use

```
buildingName='" .
mysql_real_escape_string($buildingNames) . "' AND id='" .
mysql_real_escape_string($roomId) . "'"
```

Comment: Thanks I'll make sure I'll use / look into this!

Comment: Using the single quotes fixed the entire thing! Thank you for your help, @user1502952